# snmptranslate is not working in ubuntu using snmp and snmpd

Tags: linux, ubuntu, snmp, snmpd

[image]
All cmds from the url http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/snmptranslate.1.html

or

man snmptranslate

---

snmptranslate -To

snmptranslate -Ts

and all commands are not running on my ubuntu 12.10 Linux.

I have installed snmp and snmpd using

sudo apt-get install snmpd

sudo apt-get install snmp

snmptranslate cmd I found after installing these. Please help me, If I forgot to install some package please tell me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the mibs.  Either they aren't there (sudo apt-get install snmp-mibs-downloader) or /etc/snmp/snmp.conf is not set properly.  I'd try the get and then take a look in snmp.conf to see if it sets mibdirs correctly or sets mibs incorrectly.

I did a quick web search and it looks like Ubuntu doesn't install the mibs so the above is necessary (cannot confirm as my linux box is Centos).

Comment: yes In the file /etc/snmp/snmp.conf I just comment the line
from "mibs :" to  "#mibs :" and it is working fine. Thanks @DrC